# My Atom package doesn't insert any timestamp

Tags: debugging, coffeescript, package, atom-editor

I'm working on a package for the Atom editor that should insert a timestamp in either 12-hour format or 24-hour format. Between following the instructions at the flight-manual website and looking at the code for [insert-timestamp's repo](https://github.com/alvinyangyang/insert-timestamp), I managed to cobble together what I think should give me what I need. The problem is that no timestamp gets inserted in the editor when I execute either of the commands. I've posted the main code [here](https://repl.it/Chb3/1); the ide tells me there's "unexpected indentation" on line 30 (`if H is 0:`) for some reason. I don't have much experience with Coffeescript, so it could be a syntax error on my part. Is it a problem with how I'm accessing the editor? Should I be using something other than `atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor()`?

Answer (score 1):

I believe I've found the solution. It turned out to be a syntax issue. Basically, I was using `is not` when I should've been using `isnt`. I mistakenly thought that they'd mean the same thing like they do in English. I think I understand the difference between the two of them now, however. `isnt` seems to be more for comparisons, which is what I wanted in this case. `is not` appears to deal more with whether or not a value is True. Essentially, I had syntactically valid code, but it wasn't doing what I intended it to do.

Answer (score 0):

You probably thinking of Python syntax for `if` statements, but you don't need to end them with colons in CoffeeScript.

Your code should look like this:

```
if H < 12
    p = 'AM'
    if H is 0
      H = 12
  else
    p = 'PM'
    if H isnt 12
      H = H%12
  stamp = "#{H}:#{M}:#{S}"
  editor.insertText(stamp)
```

Comment: I took the colons out, and that seems to have righted something. The problem now is that only the 24-hour format stamp works. Even if I try to insert a 12-hour stamp, I still get the 24-hour format. I've checked my keymaps, menus, and `package.json` files and can't find anything particularly wrong there, so there must be something off about either the logic of the `stamp12` function or the way it's getting executed. Could there be a problem with the usage of `Date()`?

Comment: I'd probably post that as a separate question. I came here through the `atom-editor` tag, I'd try and reach out to CoffeeScript/JavaScript developers.